# Black screen after login with user and password in MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

After login I get a black screen, if I connect a external monitor with HDMI it works in the external monitor. If I go in safe mode, the screen of the macbook also works. I already format the HDD and reinstalled IOS High Sierra and I still have the problem after login.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. Your screen is ok until you login. After logging in the screen turns black.  If you login going to safe mode, you screen is ok. is that basically it?

Comment: Have you loaded any 3rd party apps lately?  Any new apps at all?

Comment: The macbook has a clean IOS after formatting the HDD, i haven't install any program to create startup items or extensions. The profile is clean.

Comment: you didn't have any login items before the new disk?

Comment: when you say ios do you mean macOS. ios is for iPads and iphones.

Comment: Yes, sorry macOS

Comment: I had VPN, but I deleted before formatting the HDD

Comment: I will try to install OS Catalina, maybe that fix the screen

Answer (score 1):

If your computer works fine in Safe Mode that's an indication that maybe an extension or a startup item may be the culprit. If you've loaded a new extension try removing it and restarting and see if that works. After that, remove all startup items by going to System Preferences/Users & Groups and clicking on the Login Items tab at the top of the panel. Now select each startup item and remove each one by clicking on the minus sign under the app's part of the panel. After removing all login items, restart the machine in regular mode and see if it works.

If it works fine after removing the login items you can put them back one at a time and see which one causes your problem.